# In TypeScript, how do I assert the value of a class variable using a method?

Tags: typescript

I want a method that will tell typescript my client was initialised (is no longer null). Basically, I'm able to do this but in a way that seems needlessly verbose. Here's my current implementation:

```
export abstract class CacheService {
    storeClient: ICacheStoreInterface | null = null

    protected constructor(storeClientGetter: () => Promise<ICacheStoreInterface>) {
        this.logger = Container.get(Logger)
        void this.initialise(storeClientGetter)
    }

    private checkInitialisation(client: ICacheStoreInterface | null): asserts client is ICacheStoreInterface {
        if (!this.storeClient) {
            throw new Error('Attempting to access cache before initialisation')
        }
    }

    private async initialise(storeClientGetter: () => Promise<ICacheStoreInterface>) {
        try {
            this.storeClient = await storeClientGetter()
        } catch (error) {
            this.logger.error(`Error initialising cache service:\n${error}`)
        }
    }

    public async set(key: storeKey, value: any) {
        this.checkInitialisation(this.storeClient)
        await this.storeClient.set(key, value)
    }

    public async get(key: storeKey) {
        this.checkInitialisation(this.storeClient)

        return this.storeClient.get(key)
    }
}

export interface ICacheStoreInterface {
    get(key: storeKey): Promise<any>
    set(key: storeKey, value: any): Promise<void>
}

export type storeKey = number | string | symbol
```

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Mw4qadEYwFEAB0hAASFgVqAHSuq8ka9PHThgbRIATGg1G7j5VJXYDucREgDSq4ANHAbLhtB3EMF8+SQ1M3ddbvX6E8Fq9z+GSWnOAgY3HHwmIzAw0uV+5d33Q8R0OCdwmnWdEBQQ1jX8GBl1Xdc1i3dxTwxc9LxuOV7lvJUhFST9eETGA9hfOAHBgbQoCEAUizDL8PimOCENQskji1UBIFgWVPSYeE3URLpkVRH0wmY-8kN4FDQWqWoGiaZognccoySaeCJPjKSdz3JZD0CE9xEdeSWhGMYVI48BoHgGB3DAZhN1XKMdDqSUoEBeMrD5dzoJciBTCAA)

What I want to do is achieve the same result BUT without having to explicitly pass this.storeClient to the checkInitialisation method. It seems like it might be possible as both the method and the parent function have access to the variable so maybe they can share type data somehow? In essence, I'm looking for something like `asserts this.storeClient is ICacheStoreInterface` though that exact example won't work. Is this possible or am I going to have to live with the minor inconvenience of this "pointless" variable?

Comment: Your playground is incomplete and is missing a lot of definitions.

Comment: @caTS updated now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no direct support for [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) of the form `arg.prop is Type`, nor for [assertion predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) of the form `asserts arg.prop is Type`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#11117](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11117) for an open feature request for such functionality, at least for type predicates.  It's listed as "awaiting more feedback" so you might want to go there, give it a , and describe your use case (I suppose assertion predicates might be slightly off-topic there, though; not sure)... but for now it's not part of the language.

While you can't write `asserts this.storeClient is ICacheStoreInterface`, you *can* write `asserts this is {storeClient: ICacheStoreInterface}`, which is similar.  Or possibly `asserts this is this & {storeClient: ICacheStoreInterface}`, depending on whether or not the compiler requires the predicate be a strict narrowing (it doesn't seem to, but maybe there are cases where it matters).  For your example, anyway, it seems to behave as desired:

```
private checkInitialization(): asserts this is { storeClient: ICacheStoreInterface } {
    if (!this.storeClient) {
        throw new Error('Attempting to access cache before initialisation')
    }
}

public async get(key: storeKey) {
    this.checkInitialization()
    // this is now this & { storeClient: ICacheStoreInterface; }
    return this.storeClient.get(key) // okay
}
```

Such property type guards only work when the property you are narrowing is not `private`; if the property is `private` then `this` gets narrowed to `never` because an object with a `private` property is not assignable to an object with a `public` property of the same key.  So that's a limitation of this approach.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOAYSwAtgBlYKANwEtNg4BvAKDk7jWmGN3rAAdjABccAJKlMFSjF4SRNAGZZmAHzhCArrlxwAvFt242HLmCj1aCGMyjAEAEwhDcATzi4IAcx81xBCF3My44Swg7bGAnOExXNChtbGgACh4HfkERAHFgGDsocVSASkMAPjgABSgIAFt6FGAAHilyKnkHRULVJnKy9jCw2gh6WJgyRoA6eiF6GHoEASb0zr4BYRg8gpoS804AX1CLKxs7OIpMAGtFecWBAC9beldSwMIaGCIJxrhflm4ayym3EbRkHQUSigvWYB1Y+yG9GUcFSAEIfigphl1tkYAMEUMuBNagB3LTAMkAUSgtSgqQA5ABBHZ1MALIQ+ODyRCYJiEOLtOBIYDKXh-OYLJaNZ6uel7QmHBFHBGWay2ZgEdxCTDiu5SlbY4G5fKFYplAyVGr1RotMGyNbdFRqfrwhVcqCeQZuomTTGGjYiQyIEkIeaA3hGrYmmilAlcOGYWwyFE0Wn470+6bePw0KaptIAA2ptN1kuWs05ifB3BoDCYogAOkIACQsfNQA4F+UKo5hZVhMDaJACHWa7U1mCpK7AdzibEAaRnABo4DZcNpgIFgumFRipuDrrcy-QngtXt3CQgQ2G9-7cVj8lPl6ulhuL3B+xYhyPECgtTr-EnadZ3DBxF3cHdCT3A8bgle4TxlIRYzdAB6FCuV9P4iCECAyQxOAADJWFAnEQUkaR7UhHo1AAbg-ONOAcGBtCgIQMOmO9NimQCnwguA0LgCArgQEI+zYZVQEgWBxWophyPaOQqKdOSvU4HjgLnNZwJKcQrQaJpmiCdxygRJogJnTTeHAlc1w3LcIN02p9JaEYxhMiTwGgeAYHcMBmAXGcgx0OphSgOBNESCtwu4dwQogUwgA)

Comment: Very nice, thanks. The private limitation is a bit of an issue as I would normally declare this as a private variable (forgot to in this prototype code), but marking it as protected works as intended and won't expose internal state needlessly when using the class. Even though derived classes will see it, I don't see that as much of an issue.